# Some of selected resources were not cleaned. svn: E155032: Pristine text not found

Tags: svn, svn-update

I m using Eclipse JUNO on windows 7.

I m using Visual SVN as SVN Repository.

When i try to **update a file**, I am getting an error

'*Some resources were not updated.
**svn: E155004: There are unfinished work items in 'E:\SVN\tms'; run 'svn cleanup' first.***'

When i run **SVN Cleanup** by right clicking on project, I am getting an error

**'*Some of selected resources were not cleaned. svn: E155032: Pristine text not found*'**

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was to find missing pristine node and delete it directly in the local svn DB using

```
sqlite3 .svn/wc.db
sqlite> select * from pristine where checksum="$sha1$<your missing pristine here>";
```

this didn't yield any results (for missing pristine it was expected result)

```
sqlite> select * from nodes where checksum="$sha1$<your missing pristine here>";
```

I had only one item there so when I've deleted it:

```
sqlite> delete from nodes where checksum="$sha1$<your missing pristine here>";
```

and then forced svn to update deleted nodes and everything worked OK

Comment: It works. And with this, you understand how svn works. Excellent!

Answer (score 3):

Download SmartSVN and click on "validate admin area" to fix the inconsistencies.

Comment: Thanks for the blog mention :-) This question has become one of my top sources for traffic.

Comment: Link is dead, button not to be found in latest release of SmartSVN.

Comment: Removed dead link.

Answer (score 2):

You can download SmartSVN to restore lost pristine file